# customize top panel clock in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, clock

I want the top panel of Ubuntu 18.04 to show the date, DOW and time.

I tried following this link [ubuntuhandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/customize-time-date-format-ubuntu-18-04-gnome-panel/) but now all I get is a long unintelligible string of letters and numbers.

Anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

Once you installed the gnome-shell extension `clock-override` Open the extension preferences and change the values as shown below..

[image]

When you click the link "What do all these %x codes mean?" at the bottom right side of Extension preferences dialogue..

this link [GNOME Developer site](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GDateTime.html#g-date-time-format) opens, from which you can understand and adjust the format/formats according to your wish..

```
%F: equivalent to %Y-%m-%d (the ISO 8601 date format)
%A: the full weekday name according to the current locale
%T: the time in 24-hour notation with seconds (%H:%M:%S)
```

Another Customization example:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the Gnome developer site no longer leads to an explanation of the fields, and I cannot find where it should lead. I can see that some of the terms match those described by the `date` command, but not all (e.g. `%;cf`) Would you have an idea of the correct page?

Comment: Hi @PaddyLandau the link seems updated/changed. try to go through this link https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-date-command

Comment: Thank you, UnKNOWn. That is indeed for the `date` command, but doesn't include the other items (e.g. `%;cf`). I've submitted a request to the developer to update the link.