# Customising date time format | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, time, gnome-shell-extension

I recently started using Ubuntu 20.04, and I want to customise date & time format (in Windows I could write it down using a "formatted string" like %YYYY-%MM-%day). I am referring to the clock at the top on the panel.

I've found a gnome shell extension (Format Clock), but it's not compatible with gnome-shell versions >= 3.14, and I have 3.36.2. I would want to customise the format differently from the options available on the list in Region & Language. How could I do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1240111/739431

Answer (score 3):

The [Clock Override extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) ([more](https://github.com/stuartlangridge/gnome-shell-clock-override/blob/master/README.md)) should permit you to have the ANSI date format you wish in Ubuntu 20.04.