# How to show the day of the week on the desktop date with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS by default has the date and time show on the top of the desktop.

How can I include the weekday (examples: Sunday, Monday, ect)?

I want the day of the week show with the date and time how do i do this?

date I am referencing is shown in top center of screen shot.
[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1240111/739431

Comment: thanks but for ubuntu 20.04 it says Unable to locate package clock-override using sudo apt-get install clock-override

Comment: Search in gnome extensions webpage

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/

Comment: You can have more granular control of the date aspects like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263396/how-can-i-change-the-format-of-the-panel-clock-in-ubuntu-mate-20-04/1263402#1263402

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To show the weekday in addition to the date and time in Ubuntu 20.04, use the command line tool called "gsettings".

It's a good idea to view your current settings first. So open the terminal and run this command:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.interface
```

It will return various Gnome interface settings, and the one you are interested in is "clock-show-weekday" (with the value "false").

Set the "clock-show-weekday" to "true" by running this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-weekday true
```

Once you hit Enter, you will will see the weekday displayed with the weekdays shown.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work for me; the settings were changed, but the display still did not show the weekday. Using ```dconf-editor``` did the trick though, as explained in [this link](https://www.fosslinux.com/4231/how-to-show-date-and-complete-time-in-the-ubuntu-top-panel.htm).

Comment: @fabio_hirono Indeed, this answer didn't work for me.

Comment: This worked instantly for me on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.  Sorry, not sure why it didn't work for either of you.

Comment: This seems to have no effect on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Worked instantly for me on Pop!_OS 22.04.

Comment: Worked instantly on Ubuntu 22.04.1, Thanks

Comment: Worked instantly on Ubuntu 23.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can try this in the terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-weekday true
```

Answer (score 5):

Install GNOME Tweaks like this:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

After installing it open the app named "Tweaks", find menu item named "Top Bar" and then enable weekday:

[image: Screenshot]

GNOME Tweaks is a wonderful tool that should be installed after installing `synaptic` but before installing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other excellent answers, it's possible to get the following error/warning while changing `org.gnome.desktop.interface` settings:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

the issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/glib-feedstock/issues/19) and the general answer is that environment variable GIO_EXTRA_MODULES need to point to the location of gio modules like so:

```
export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/
```

To make the above permanent, this needs to be put in .bashrc

After doing so, `org.gnome.desktop.interface` will be saved.