# How can I change the format of the panel clock in Ubuntu Mate 20.04?

Tags: panel, ubuntu-mate, clock

The default format is XX:XX AM/PM

How can I change it to XX:XX AM/PM Weekday Month Date ?

Searching offers up dconf-editor solutions that don't apply to 20.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clock indicator in Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS is controlled by `indicator-datetime` service, so to customize it, you have to use commands below:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format custom

gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format '%l:%M %p %A %B %d'
```

it probably was doable in dconf-editor, you would have had to set the time-format to "custom" in order for your changes to show...

Comment: Thanks! worked great.  The dconf-editor fixes I found suggested changing `org / mate / panel / objects / clock / prefs` but that entry didn't exist in my system.  Your suggestion of `com / canonical / indicator / datetime` let me find it in dconf-editor.

Comment: Where can we find instructions on what those `%x` mean?

Comment: @Andyc in your terminal..... `man date`

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well but I want the date and time on different rows. I can do this with `%n` but I don't know how to change the font size? `<span>` is not recognized in the `custom-time-format` field any more it seems?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 21.04, I installed dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then I ran it and set the following keys to the following values to change the time format:

```
/org/ayatana/indicator/datetime/time-format = custom
/org/ayatana/indicator/datetime/custom-time-format = %a, %F %T
```

The custom formats can be found in [strftime(3) - Linux manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

I also showed multiple time zones using:

```
/org/ayatana/indicator/datetime/show-locations true
/org/ayatana/indicator/datetime/locations "['America/Toronto', 'Europe/London', 'Australia/Sydney']"
```

The list of time zone can be taken from: [List of tz database time zones - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)