# How can I customize the time and date format in the top bar, without a shell extension?

Tags: gnome, time, date

There are several Gnome Shell extensions, but how do they work? Can I do what they do? I want to use a customized date/time format string myself, without requiring a shell extension. Is there documentation for whatever top-bar APIs the shell extensions are using? Ubuntu 21.10, Gnome 40.5.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263396/how-can-i-change-the-format-of-the-panel-clock-in-ubuntu-mate-20-04/1263402#1263402

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format custom

gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format '%l:%M %p %A %B %d'
```

**Option 2**

You will first need to find the region and city format.

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

You will find a long list of region/city names.
Once you find the correct entry:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone your_time_zone
```

**Option 3**

Go to **Settings > Date & Time** and change it.

Comment: When entering: "gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format custom" - I get: "No such schema 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime' ". System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS